# how can we run Neptune graph database on docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-neptune, localstack

how can we run Neptune graph database on docker

Since Neptune DB has been productized recently it is not available on Localstack can someone guide me how to deploy AWS Neptune DB Service into docker container

Comment: Could you elaborate your question?

Answer (score 4):

You don't deploy neptune, you deploy a client application which uses an appropriate client library to access neptune.  The neptune software/hardware is managed by AWS and you can't access it except via API.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that you're attempting to create a local Neptune compatible docker container (i.e. some docker container with a compatible API). This would be similar to using [minios](https://hub.docker.com/r/minio/minio/) when performing local integration testing with S3. If this is indeed what you're in search of I'd recommend using [tinkerpop's gremlin-server image](https://hub.docker.com/r/tinkerpop/gremlin-server/). This should get the job done for you since Neptune uses Gremlin for its query language.

Answer (score 3):

For now, I found only one way. It is Pro version of Localstack. It contains Neptune DB. https://localstack.cloud/features/ Unfortunately free version of test container does not support DB interface. =(

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Does LocalStack Pro support RDF style queries (SPARQL)?

Answer (score 2):

Neptune is a fully managed graph database, and not a binary that can be independently deployed in your personal containers or infrastructure. You can run your client application in your own custom docker containers, and setup your network such that the container makes requests to the managed Neptune cluster that you have created.

Hope this helps.